# Why setVisibility causes NullPointerException?

Tags: android

I have the following:

```
private OnItemSelectedListener CommentCodeListener = new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Log.i(LogTAG, "spinner selection: "+ position);
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view2=inflater.inflate(R.layout.commentdialog, null);
        CheckBox CommentPaper = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.CommentPaper);
        EditText CommentField = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.CommentOtherField);
        String[] arr = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.CommentCodeListValues);
        String CommentCode = arr[position];
        int CommentCodeInt = Integer.parseInt(arr[position]);
        Log.i(LogTAG, "spinner selection (int): "+ CommentCodeInt);
        CommentPaper.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        CommentField.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if( (CommentCodeInt >= 21 && CommentCodeInt <= 31) || CommentCodeInt == 41 ) {
            Log.i(LogTAG, "set CommentPaper visible");
            CommentPaper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if( (CommentCodeInt >=22 && CommentCodeInt <=33) || (CommentCodeInt >= 35 && CommentCodeInt <=36 ) || (CommentCodeInt >= 42 && CommentCodeInt <=43 ) ) {
            Log.i(LogTAG, "set CommentPaper visible");
        }
        if( CommentCodeInt >=41 && CommentCodeInt <=43 ) {
            Log.i(LogTAG, "set CommentField visible");
            CommentField.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        Log.i(LogTAG, "nothing selected");
    }

};
```

The layout:

```
    <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/CommentCode_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/MultiLineComment"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/commentLabel"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="3"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" >
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/CommentOtherField"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/commentLabel"
            android:visibility="visible" >
        </EditText>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/CommentPaper"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/reportCheckBox"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/AddCommentButton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/okButton" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please note, that the layout above (commentdialog.xml) is a Dialog.

The CommentCodeListener is called when I select something with a spinner. Everything works when setVisibility is commented.
I have tried with

- `CheckBox CommentPaper = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.CommentPaper);`
- `CheckBox CommentPaper = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.CommentPaper);`
- `CheckBox CommentPaper = (CheckBox) view2.findViewById(R.id.CommentPaper);`

but no luck.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the layout for the items that are being selected?
Also, why don't you follow [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367), which dictate camelCase variable names?

Comment: What is the meaning of inflating view2?

Comment: Layout is inserted to the question.view2 inflating the commentdialog.xml, which contains the spinner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I set my dialog global:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private Dialog AddComment_Dialog;
  ..
```

And this way I can call it anywhere I want.
So I just typed:

```
AddComment_Dialog.findViewById(R.id.sometext);
```

I do not know why the original code won't work but it is taken care of.
Thank everyone!

Answer (score 0):

No setinvisible can not cause NPE. CommentPaper/CommentField is just null and you are trying to use it

Comment: Those are not null. Tested.

Answer (score 0):

You are inflating `commentdialog.xml` so if your `CheckBox` and `EditText` are in that `layout` then you need to use `view2` to initialize them

```
(CheckBox) view2.findViewById(R.id.CommentPaper);
```

and same with `EditText` or any other `View` in that `layout`.

Comment: Yes, that's why I created view2 but I got NPE. Weird!

Comment: But you are using `view.findViewById(R.id.someId);` instead of `view2.findViewById(R.id.someId);` Not weird, you are just looking in the wrong `layout`

Comment: Yes, you are right! When I use view.findViewB... then nothing happens. I mean EditText and Checkbox are are not disappearing.

Comment: What about when you use `view2.findViewById`?

Comment: I wanted to write that, sory !

Comment: Could it be because you are setting them back to `visible` a few lines later or somewhere else?

Comment: When I comment the conditions out, the edittext and checkbox are still visible.

Comment: Is this `layout` inflated somewhere else?

Comment: Nope, here first. I can reopen though.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an example how I set the visibility of a Checkbox in AlertDialog, I know it is not the same as in the firs post but maybe it helps someone.

```
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new  AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog, null);

            CheckBox checkBox=(CheckBox)layout.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            builder.setView(layout)  //some Böttons
                            .setPositiveButton("Zurück",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) { }});

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
```